# Global.cs Error Handling using System.Net.Mail

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, http-status-code-404, global, system.net.mail

I am using the Application_Error in the Global class to handle 404s.

Once a 404 is caught I send an email for the purpose of logging it. To do this I call a static method to write the error.

```
ErrorHandler.WriteError(Exception ex)
```

Within this method I create a new instance of my **EmailHandler** in order to initialise the **System.Net.Mail** class. Within my **EmailHandler** object I have a private member

```
private MailMessage m_mail = null;
```

In the constructor of the **EmailHandler** class I create a new **MailMesage** instance in order to construct the email.

```
public EmailHandler()
{
   m_mail = new MailMessage(); 
}
```

At this point I get the following error.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException
"The handle is invalid."
```

I need to point out that this only happens when the request is to a specific file only (such as a **www.mysite.com/random-incorrect-image.jpg**).

It **doesn't** happen when I am requesting a page like **www.mysite.com/random-incorrect-page.aspx**

Comment: What is your IIS version and how exactly did you configure 404 trapping ? Through an error page execution ?

Comment: @jbl I am just running this on vs2010 asp.net development server at the moment. I capture the 404 by getting the HttpException from the last Server Error. From HttpException you can get the error code.

Comment: But, as 404 on static files are not processed through asp.net, where, and when, in your code are you invoking System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.GetLastError() ?

Comment: As I said above in the Application_Error section of the global.cs

Comment: As far as I know, application_error should not trigger on 404s on static files. Did you display the error message in your exception ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try the following for static file 404 :

Configure custom 404 in your web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors>
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/yourpath/yourcustom404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  </httpErrors>
```

404 Redirection for static files will then occur to http://www.mysite.com/yourpath/yourcustom404.aspx?404;http://www.mysite.com/random-incorrect-image.jpg

You can then process the queryString to extract the url in the pageLoad of custom404.aspx, send your email, and display a friendly message

You can do the same for aspx pages.
In your web.config :

```
 <customErrors mode="On">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="/yourpath/yourcustom404.aspx" />       
</customErrors>
```

the redirection will be slightly different though :

http://www.mysite.com/yourpath/yourcustom404.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/random-incorrect-page.aspx